# Distcc ld error

Tags: compiling, make, cmake, g++

I want to compile supertuxkart for notebook on my main computer (v-mint, with distcc daemon). My actions:

1. Clone `git+svn repos` from official sources. (`compile/{stk-code,stk-assets}`).
2. `cd compile/stk-code`
3. `mkdir cmake_build && cmake_build`
4. `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/distcc -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=g++`
5. `export DISTCC_HOSTS=v-mint`
6. `make -j 14`

   ```
   Compilling...
   Linking CXX executable bin/supertuxkart
     //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   distcc[5704] ERROR: compile (null) on localhost failed
   make[2]: *** [bin/supertuxkart] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/supertuxkart.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2
   ```

   What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to specify the need library? Try to add `-lm` to the compiling command.

Comment: This code can compille correctly on any computer. This problem generate only with distcc. (simply `cmake .. && make` works correctly)

Comment: you may want to open CMakeLists.txt and search for `target_link_libraries(...)` there. if there's no `lm` in the list, try to add it there.

Comment: Also, try running `make VERBOSE=1`, if the above suggestion doesn't help.

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with whether the underlying compiler is invoked as gcc (which doesn't link libm automatically as one of its stdlibs) or as g++ (which does, I think: see [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1033940/4440445) for example). However I'm not familiar with distcc - perhaps there's a flag or environment variable to make it operate in "g++ mode"?

Comment: ... maybe try `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/distcc g++"`?

Comment: @steeldriver, `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is path to file, but I haven't got file `/usr/bin/distcc g++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create small script (I'm using distg++ in my PATH) contains it:

```
distcc g++ "$@"
```

and run `cmake`:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=distg++
```